# Choosing 'scoring' parameter in random search

Tags: machine-learning, python, hyperparameter, precision-recall

i'm still confused about scoring parameter in randomized search

First i want to know if my machine learning model is overfit or not. I use roc auc score between train and test.. turns out there is large gap between roc auc score between train and test. So i decided to do hyperparameter tuning.

For information this case i want to maximize my recall score more than precision.

So in randomized search cv what scoring parameter should i choose? Is it recall or roc_auc?

Comment: What do you mean by "scoring parameter"?

Comment: @Tim you can see it in here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter